# How to pass an OsString to a Win32 API call

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I had this code working with `CString` using the xxxA versions of the calls. Now I want to use the xxxW versions and cant work out how to pass an `OsString` to the call.

```
let cname = OsString::from("my backend class");
let brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0));
let cl = WNDCLASSW {
    style: 0,
    lpfnWndProc: Some(callback),
    cbClsExtra: 0,
    cbWndExtra: std::mem::size_of::<&i32>() as i32,
    hInstance: handle,
    hIcon: 0 as HICON,
    hCursor: LoadCursorW(std::ptr::null_mut(), IDC_ARROW),
    hbrBackground: brush, //(COLOR_WINDOW + 1) as HBRUSH,
    lpszMenuName: 0 as LPWSTR,
    lpszClassName: cname.as_ptr(), <<<=======
};
```

`OsString` does not have an `as_ptr()` method. Should I not use `OsString`? If not what should I use?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but WinSafe's [`WString`](https://docs.rs/winsafe/0.0.5/winsafe/struct.WString.html) would save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/index.html#on-windows):

> On Windows, [`OsStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html) implements the `std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt` trait, which provides an [`encode_wide`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.encode_wide) method. This provides an iterator that can be [`collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect)ed into a vector of [`u16`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u16.html).

The documentation for [`encode_wide`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.encode_wide) also states:

> Note that the encoding does not add a final null terminator.

Thus:

```
use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt;

let cname = OsStr::new("my backend class")
    .encode_wide()
    .chain(Some(0)) // add NULL termination
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();

// and then call cname.as_ptr() as you are currently doing
```

Comment: TY. Considering that OsString exists specifcally to be used to pass utf16 to ffi calls on  windows thats pretty fiddly. Compared to CString's as_ptr

Comment: @pm100: `OsString` is cheaply convertible to and from Rust-native strings—internally it uses the [WTF-8](https://simonsapin.github.io/wtf-8/) encoding. Windows requires UTF-16—hence conversion is required.

Comment: actually I dont care about OsString. I just want the 'best' way to pass a string to a win32 call that takes UTF16 with a null terminator. Is there a better way?

Comment: @pmt100: No, this is exactly the best way.

Comment: this doesnt work as it doesnt zero terminate the string, so I did "xxxxxxx\0"

Comment: @pm100: Quite right, I’ve added that to the answer.